# Access current model in javascript template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to work with a backbone template in the following way:

- the template has some js attached that listens for changes on a dropdown and looks up some info
- the returned info needs to be set on the current model i'm working with

The trouble i'm having is:

- i dont see any way to incorporate the event listener into the backbone view object since the elements on the page dont exist to bind to ... am i wrong on this?
- in the template itself, i dont see how i can access the current model that is being rendered in the template so i can call model.set('property',value)

Comment: Backbone View event hashes wrap event delegation calls (e.g. jQuery's .on) so the elements don't need to be in the DOM yet. As far as access to model data, you generally pass it in to your templating function. Some code and more context would be helpful in helping you.

Comment: the template i'm rendering is an edit screen that saves the values on submit.  However, based on the user's selections, i need to retrieve supplemental data and include that in the save.  I figured populating a bunch of hidden elements wouldn't really be wise or efficient.  I guess I could do the lookup before the save ...  but since I need to retrieve the values for other parts of the page, it seems like a waste.  Good question though ... it has me thinking of some alternatives

Comment: You don't access the model inside the template, you use events to trigger actions in the view. Perhaps a small example would be helpful.

Comment: thanks all for your help ... after @muistooshort last comment, i realized i could directly listen to the event on the particular element i need right from backbone -- wasnt getting this at first